# MathJax website is Shutting Down? From where we now getting support?

Tags: support, mathjax, help

SE network mandates a programing language called MathJax, to format chemistry or math equations.

The left click on MathJax processed text shows the following icons:

[image: MathJax processed text on Puzzling SE].
Fig 1. MathJax processed text from Puzzling SE [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49065/what-is-a-united-word).

Now, a further click on "about MathJax" and "MathJax Help"; leads to following flashcard:

[image: MathJax Help]

Fig.2:  MathJax Help

The help box refers the website.

[**https://www.mathjax.org/**](https://www.mathjax.org/). **(Certainly it is the official website of MathJax?)**

Now shockingly; the website tells; they are closing their service! 
[image]

Also it is not very clear to me from their [announcement](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/) link that whether they are completely closing their service or it is a temporary pause. They also telling to download local copies.

.......................................................

**Now, how the SE questions and answers will survive if MathJax provider official website shuts down?** what alternatives are being thought? Is there any chance of existing Mathjax and mixed-formatted portions of Q/A could break-down?

Comment: MathJax is not closing down. The MathJax **CDN** (Content Delivery Network) is.

Comment: In other words, your username here is very apt... They are shutting down the hosting service that many sites use in order to get the MathJax JavaScript libraries - this means most such sites will need to find an alternative hosting solution. The project itself (and www.mathjax.org itself) are not closing down.

Comment: Reopened to prevent confusion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: But... the question duped clearly explains the situation without much chance of confusion: that SE handled the shutdown already.

Comment: @Nathan people might think MathJax itself has been shut down. The answer here clearly says is was not, so IMO it can send better signal.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah so does the linked dupe. That's the point of the linked dupe. Which also describes the resolution. You made a boo boo here. :P

Comment: @Shadow We're really not responsible for hosting a separate question for someone who completely misread a message and thought MathJax was shutting down altogether. If not a duplicate, this is off-topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Peter from MathJax here.

MathJax is not shutting down.

Only one particular service that we provided at cdn.mathjax.org has been retired (in fact it is now redirecting to a similar service).

There are numerous alternatives to that service and it is easy to switch to another free CDN such as cdnjs.com (or to host your own copy). All StackExchange sites already migrated back in April and have been working just as smoothly.

We at MathJax continue to support our community the same way we always have. And of course we are particularly grateful for StackExchange who support our development as a MathJax sponsor.

Comment: Thanks, btw, for being so actively involved and responding to MathJax questions here! Super cool.

Comment: Maybe "The MathJax CDN is shutting down on April 30, 2017!" should be reworded now that the date has passed.

Comment: I'll second Gerry on that one - and if there is a date by which the redirection will stop, it would be nice to have that noted on the site as well. (And I'll also second Jason on thanking y'all for being so active on this.)

Comment: The blurb was updated a few days ago. Can you check if you're still seeing the old one? As for the final shutdown, we don't know yet. We'll have to see how the redirect works out in the long run. At least three months, I'm relatively confident we can extend it to the end of the year but quite possibly much longer.